# Copy range by + 2 offset

Tags: excel

How do I copy a range to another cell where the range is added with 2 instead of 1?

If I have Column `A1: =B$1:B2` and then copy `A1` downwards it will become `=B$1:B3, =B$1:B4, =B$1:B5`.

What I need is: `=B$1:B4, =B$1:B6, =B$1:B8`.

How do I accomplish this in Exel/Xcelsius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one more option is to use `INDEX`:

```
=B$1:INDEX(B:B,ROW()*2)
```

**UPD:**

Here is [**test workbook**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwdozdimo55891u/simoco_t.xlsx) with OP's formula.

Comment: Thanks, Can u give me an example with this formule: =SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J$3:J6)/SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L$3:L6)*100 -> L6 needs to be added by 2.. Thanks in advance

Comment: try this one in cell `A1`: `=SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J:$J,ROW(J3)*2))/SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L:$L,ROW(L3)*2))*100`.

Comment: @user3248190, in cell `A1` this formula would give you `$L$3:L6`, in `A2` `$L$3:L8` and so on

Comment: what error exactly have you got? and what is your local separator in formula: semicolon `;` or comma `,`?

Comment: try to use this one as well: `=SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J:$J;ROW(J3)*2))/SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L:$L;ROW(L3)*2))*100`

Comment: Thanks, the first formula I am getting the error: 'The formula you typer contains an error', the second formula I've got an NAME error: "does not recognize text in a formula". Separator is ; thanks again bart

Comment: it seems that XCELSIUS doesn't support `ROW()` function.. can you use additional column in your worksheet?

Comment: Yes that is not a problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: so, in that case write in example in `Z1` 1, in `Z2` 2 , in `Z3` 3 and so.. then use this formula: `=SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J:$J;Z3*2))/S‌​UM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L:$L;Z3*2))*100`

Comment: Sorry but again the error 'The formula you typer contains an error'. even if I use Excel without Xcelsius.. Regards

Comment: Ok, here is my test workbook. Try it: [link to file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwdozdimo55891u/simoco_t.xlsx)

Comment: Simoco THANKS it workerd :) really nice! But what I do not understand is, If I copy the formula from you here it is not working I get an error. But if I copy the formula from your excel file it is working.. I have checked it many times there are no differtens between

Comment: this one works not: =SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J:$J;L26*2))/S‌​UM(‌ CDM_Fact_Organization!$L$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L:$L;L26*2))*100
this one works : =SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J:$J;L26*2))/SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L$3:INDEX(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L:$L;L26*2))*100

Comment: Do u know how this is possible ? because it is exact the same :|

Comment: In second formula second `SUM` word is wrong (`..../SUM()` ) . Maybe you typed it not in engllish lang:)

Comment: I have checked but (copied both formulas in notepad) can't see the difference.. It is not very important but I think it is very strange.. but the formula works, that is the most important. thanks again

Comment: Ok, try to compare next two words in excel. Put `S‌​‌​UM` in `A1` and `SUM` in `A2` and compare them in any cell: `=A1=A2` :)

Comment: I do not get it? it is the same? see my image: www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=f21rzilmz1od02ct7nip.png Can you explain? Am I stuppid?

Comment: You have the same result as I, the are not euqal:) I do not why, but if you split each character and use `=UNICODE(A1)` for each character they would be the same, but not toghether

Comment: oke, thats strange. but thanks for all you're help today! really appreciate :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

What about `=INDIRECT("B$1:B" & ROW(A1)*2)`

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do it with this formule: =SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J$3:J6)/SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$L$3:L6)*100 -> L6 needs to be added by 2...

Comment: If you want to start with 6: `=SUM(CDM_Fact_Organization!$J$3:J6)/SUM(INDIRECT("CDM_Fact_Organization!$L$3:L" & ROW(A3)*2))*100`

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately Xcelsius does not support INDIRECT. So I will try INDEX.